# Computer freezes frequently after SSD upgrade

Tags: windows-10, ssd, freeze

Recently I replaced my HDD with an SSD (didn't bring over old files) and booted up using Windows on a USB flash drive I made. It now generally does seems to run faster. However, it frequently freezes when I try to do something (e.g. starting a program, even opening a new tab). The graphics don't freeze and my USB devices still remain responsive. After about 1 minute of being frozen, it goes back to normal and finishes what I tried to do. It is much more frequent directly after I boot up.

I'm using Windows 10, in case that helps.

When it does freeze, the task manager seems fine, and none of the usage readings change. It just instantly freezes, without any updates on the task manager. Also, the percentage usages read on the task manager appear to be normal levels.

What is happening, and how can this be fixed (I'd like to get the SSD to work...)?

**Edit:** When I look in the task manager, it says the SSD is only getting read / write speeds of up to about 2 MB/s, when it should be getting around 500 MB/s...

Comment: which SSD do you use? Also which chipset drivers do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this may not be a very helpful answer, but over time it has stopped freezing. It seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a faulty SSD.  Hard Drive manufacturers will have test programs to run on your drives before you send them back, so follow the instructions found on their website to test your drive.